# Rotation event handling GLTF-MODEL

Tags: aframe

Newbie to Aframe. I managed to deploy Image Tracking HTML (Trex sample from https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js). Also, I downloaded GLTF model from Sketchfab and it works as well. Now I have the GLTF object when I scan the Trex picture using my phone. Next step, I am looking for information whether we can rotate the model (GLTF) using drag gesture on the phone but I don't find much info. Is it possible? If so, can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Thanks Adam. It looks promising. Let me work on it and I will keep it posted here

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Thanks for pointing me to the correct direction. I have successfully added the rotation and pinch to the GLTF model. However, the rotation behaviour is not what I expected. I am expecting a horizontal rotation and I couldn't achieve it after playing with the XYZ axis. Appreciate if you have any idea how I can achieve horizontal rotation. This is the URL that I followed https://github.com/jsimonson2013/ar-sample/blob/master/index.html